# I want to move my washer and dryer to the opposite side of the mobile home

Tags: electrical

I am new to mobile home repairs and modifications.As far as I can tell all the wiring is overhead. If I move my washer and dryer to the other side of the home I will have to run the
wiring underneath. Is this legal?

Comment: `Is this legal?` ... how is anyone supposed to guess which regulations apply in your country? ... please do not assume that everyone knows where you live

Comment: Also if you go under you'll need to protect the wires from when the home is being transported (much more than via the roof).

Comment: Questions such as this only become valid with more information - such as where in the world. Could even be contained in your profile!

Comment: @MrR - 'mobile home' is rather a misnomer. Often not meaning a caravan, camper, etc., but a prefabricated box (on wheels) that must be carried on a transporter, not the road, so the wheels are basically there to obviate use of a crane on site - where it will probably end its days.

Comment: @Tim most US mobile homes are actually transported from the manufacturer to their installation site on their own wheels. Often, the wheels are removed and some sort of foundation is put under the frame. Of course, they do usually stay there until they're hauled off to the junk yard (by another truck or a tornado), however, they _can_ be moved again by reinstalling the wheels and removing the underpinning, so I don't think Mr. R's comment was all that off-base.

Comment: @FreeMan - MrR is in Oz, I'm in UK, OP is, well, we don't know (I have a problem with the 'air of mystery' profile - often answers need to be geographically orientated ), so why do you mention US? In UK, mobile homes have wheels (no brakes) just to trundle the last few hundred yards on site.

Comment: And, when I click your profile, @Tim, I can see that, but you can't see that when you click mine (it's not there). That's why I prefaced with "US" - makes it real obvious right up front. If our OP is _also_ in the US, he knows this info applies to him. If not, it probably doesn't. Just makes it easier on everyone.

Comment: @FreeMan - not knowing OP's location does mean any answer may not be accurate, though. Citing it in the question would have been a good idea. I guessed your location - my other half's a scouser - supports Liverpool United or something...